# Alias `iojs` to run the io.js version installed with nvm

Tags: node.js, bash, nvm, io.js

Using nvm, I've installed several versions of Node.js and the latest version of io.js. Finally, there's also a system-wide installation of Node.js (which is the default set for nvm).

Now, I'd like to alias `iojs` (not in the nvm but in the bash way) to always run the only installed version of io.js.

Doing things like `alias iojs='nvm run iojs'` won't work:

```
$ iojs -v
Running node system
v0.12.0
```

The only solution I came up with is:

```
iojs() {
    NVM=`nvm version`
    nvm use iojs > /dev/null # will mute the command 
    node $@
    nvm use $NVM > /dev/null
}
```

Do you have a better idea?

By the way: `alias iojs='nvm exec iojs node'` doesn't work either:

```
$ iojs -v
system version is not installed yet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing `alias iojs='nvm run iojs'` your alias conflicts with the "iojs" in your alias definition

So if you're defining your alias like

`alias myiojs="nvm run iojs"`

the command `myiojs -v` should work fine:

```
$ myiojs -v
Running io.js v1.3.0
v1.3.0
```

Comment: You're right, I'm proably just better off using the nvm command because even the function I came up with conflicts with .nvmrc files :-(